# Convert UTC date for display using date-fns while keeping UTC timestamp as tag for database

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I have dates attached to entries in a json file that stores them in chronological order. I would like to use [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v1.30.1/docs/format) to format the dates for display in the UI, while keeping the granular data in the timestamp.

Currently it its stored as `2019-03-01T04:33:26.114Z` in the json and displays as "Fri Mar 01 2019 04:33:26 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" in the UI.

In util.js, `date` is constructed as:

```
export const constant = x => () => x;

// date in local time constructor
export function CreateDateAsUTC(date) {
  return new Date(
    Date.UTC(
      date.getFullYear(),
      date.getMonth(),
      date.getDate(),
      date.getHours(),
      date.getMinutes(),
      date.getSeconds())
    )
}
```

Adding the `var format` block with date-fns formatting to the display code in archive.js results in <strike>errors</strike> no change to the UTC date format:

```
import {format, compareAsc} from 'date-fns/esm'

...

const getDate = ({ date }) => date;

// this block is intended to format using date-fns but doesn't 
var format = require('date-fns/format')
format(date, [format='dddd, DD MMMM, YYYY, h:mm'])
//=> true

//without the var format block this displays with lengthy formatting.
const entryTemplate = ({ date, passage, question, answer }) =>
  html`<li>
  <h3>${date}</h3>
    <dl>
      <dt>Passage</dt>
      <dd>${passage}</dd>
      <dt>Question</dt>
      <dd>${question}</dd>
      <dt>Answer</dt>
      <dd>${answer}</dd>
    </dl>
  </li>`;
```

I am new to javascript and not sure what the best approach would be to modify the dates for display.

Comment: "*results in errors*" Then why don't you include those in your question?

Comment: apologies - they're not errors, they're null results

Comment: `[format='dddd, DD MMMM, YYYY, h:mm']` is probably not what you want. It will *replace* the imported `format` with a string. Also, `date-fns/format` "[returns] the formatted date string", it does not change the original `date`.

Comment: I have corrected the display date to clarify the issue. The dates are not to be changed, only the format of the dates.